# How to use the 'set membership symbol' $\in$ for functions?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

For example, how would you indicate that the function $f(x) = x^2 + 1$ only accepts real numbers $\mathbb{R}$ and not complex numbers $\mathbb{C}$? Would you write it like this?:

$f(x) = x^2 + 1, x\in\mathbb{R}$

Same with: $f(z) = z^2 +1, z\in\mathbb{C}$, is this the correct notation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is not wrong. In higher math the usual notation is to say that $f:\Bbb R\to \Bbb R$ satisfies
$$f(x) =x^2+1$$
but you rarely see this in an intro calculus course.

If we declare that $f:A\to B$ is a function, we are saying that the domain of $f$ is $A$ and $f$ takes values in $B$.

Comment: Alright, thanks a lot! What does that notation exactly mean though? Could you explain that to me? $f:\Bbb R\to \Bbb R$

Comment: @Stall Sure, added an explanation.

Comment: Ah, thanks! So if there's a function $f(x) = \frac{1}{x}$, would you write it as:

$f:\Bbb x\ne0\to\Bbb R$ ?

Comment: @Stall The domain would be a set. You'd write $f:\{x\in \Bbb R:x\neq 0\}\to\Bbb R$.

Comment: Ah interesting. But wouldn't it be unnecessary/superfluous to mention R twice? Since you already defined that $x\in\ R$.

Comment: @Stall $x$ is a dummy variable that doesn't "stick around." You have to specify every time.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the quick and great help!

Comment: @Stallmp No problem.

Comment: To the proposer: The convention is that the notation $f:\Bbb R$ \ $\{0\}\to \Bbb R$ means that $f$ is a function whose domain is $\Bbb R$ \ $\{0\},$ and that $f$ takes value(s) in $\Bbb R.$    You have to specify the domain .   If you write $f:x\ne 0\to \Bbb R$ then it is clear that $0$ is not in $dom(f)$ but it is not clear what, if anything, is in $dom(f)$.